# How can I check if MSBuild is using .NET Core?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I am using [`Scripty.MsBuild`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scripty.MsBuild/0.7.4) to generate some files in a ASP.NET Core project. When I build from VS2017, the target runs successfully, but when I build via `dotnet`, I get the error:

```
Scripty.MsBuild.targets(31,5): error MSB4062: The "ScriptyTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\geirsagberg\.nuget\packages\scripty.msbuild\0.7.4\build\\..\tools\Scripty.MsBuild.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

My current workaround is to disable `Scripty.MsBuild` for `Release` configuration:

```
<PackageReference Include="Scripty.MsBuild" Version="0.7.4" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" />
```

This lets me build from VS in debug mode, and build with `dotnet` on the build server.

However, I still want to be able to do `dotnet run` locally in debug mode (for running from VSCode). Therefore I need to include the `PackageReference` conditionally, based on whether Visual Studio's MSBuild is running, or the `dotnet` version. As far as I can tell, these two have the exact same version number; am I missing something?

**Is there a property in MSBuild I can use to distinguish between the VS MSBuild and the `dotnet` one?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out there is a property `MSBuildRuntimeType` that can be either `Core`, `Mono` or `Full`. So I can do:

```
<PackageReference Include="Scripty.MsBuild" Version="0.7.4" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'!='Core'" />
```

[Reference from SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/d8e9a98dafd629010c13c622a00f72a4343a839e/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets#L19-L22)

Comment: Update: `MSBuildRuntimeType` is now [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019), so if you're looking at this and unsure if it's a stable API, it seems to be.